# Take the average of all hours of a collection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to Take the average of all the hours and minutes of a field called "TS" in the table called bitacoratiempo, that field is of type varchar and its structure is this TS: "00:05"
I have been able to change from varchar to time in this way:

```
((@prom_tiempo_visita.TS).to_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

How can I get the average of all these hours and minutes

I've tried this

```
@prom_tiempo_visita = Bitacoratiempo.prom_tiempo_visita(params).average(:TS)
```

but I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT AVG([bitacoratiempos].[TS]) FROM [bitacoratiempos] left outer join clientes on bitacoratiempos.Codigo=clientes.IdCli WHERE ((bitacoratiempos.RutaId = N''161'' or N''161'' = '''') AND (bitacoratiempos.IdEmpresa = N''208'')) AND (bitacoratiempos.HI >= N''2014-12-01'' AND bitacoratiempos.HI <= N''2016-12-01'')'):
  app/controllers/ventas_controller.rb:20:in `busqueda_general_graficos'
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it by yourself? Can we see your code to fix it?

Comment: @DmitryTonkonogov updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have already found that you need to convert your values to be able to apply the average operation. Unfortunately `#average` can be applied only to the ActiveRecord instance. It means that you need to count it all in a plain code.
Another thing is the question - what is average for time? It can't be applied directly to time-related datatypes. At first you need to convert them to integers. One of the obvious ways is to convert it to seconds.

So, step by step:

```
# Get all values to find average 
values = Bitacoratiempo.pluck(:TS)
# Convert it to plain integers
conv_values = values.map {|val| Time.parse(val).seconds_since_midnight }
# Then count the average
avg = conv_values.sum / conv_values.length
# Optionally convert it to the string
nice_string = Time.at(avg).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

It will work only for values less than 24 hours. If you need it for more than 24 hours, I believe it's better for you to make it by yourself after thorough investigation of what my code actually does.

> The hint: update coercion functions on the second and fourth lines

Comment: many thanks my friend, your code worked for me. Very interesting your code,  Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need to find the average of a collection time.

let an array be

```
time_array = [2016-12-23 10:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-24 11:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-25 12:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-26 13:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-27 14:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-28 15:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-29 16:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-30 17:16:59 +0530, 2016-12-31 18:16:59 +0530, 2017-01-01 19:16:59 +0530]
```

you can find the average by

```
DateTime.strptime(((time_array.map{|t| t.to_i}.sum)/time_array.size).to_s,'%s')
```